# SharePoint Foundation Display Template - managed metadata missing

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-results, display-template

I'm trying to customize the display of search results in a SharePoint Foundation 2013 environment.

Since this environment doesn't have the publishing feature, I'm creating the HTML display template on a SharePoint Server farm and copying across the generated javascript file. This works - I can see HTML that I've added to the display template.

However, I'm not having any luck with updating the ManagedPropertyMapping tag. I've used the browser debugger to examine the ctx.currentItem. None of the properties that I've added show up.

I've used the codeplex SharePoint Query Tool to verify that the properties are present in my content.

I've tried recreating the search index and triple checked my syntax.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm a step closer. I noticed that the JavaScript file generated includes a property with the values from the ManagedProperty tag in the file. I copied/pasted this to the JavaScript file I copied to the Foundation server. I then loaded the Search Result Types page in the site collection. This had a message that the properties had changed. I clicked the update link. Now some of my properties are coming through. I can't figure out why I'm getting some, but not others.